# How to mock a Generic Abstract class

Tags: moq

Assuming I have an Interface IReportBuilderService and concrete class ReportBuilderService

```
e.g. public class ReportBuilderService : IReportBuilderService { }
```

I can start to mock this service with Moq as such

```
Mock<IReportBuilderService> _reportBuilderServiceMock = new Mock<IReportBuilderService>();
```

And mock expectations etc on the mock class, ok no problems.

Question: How do I mock the following method signature?

```
public abstract class ReportBuilder<TReport> where TReport : Report, new()
```

where  a TReport is defined as

```
public class SomeReport : ReportBuilder<Report>, IMapper{}
```

And Report class is simply

```
public class Report { }
```

In the abstract class ReportBuilder there are a series of Property Get/ Sets, it is the value of these that I’m trying to fake/mock.

But I can’t begin to get the correct mock on this abstract class to start with

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Given that your abstract class looks like this:

```
public abstract class ReportBuilder<TReport> where TReport : Report, new() 
{
    public abstract Int32 SomeThing { get; set; }
}
```

there's no problem in mocking it at all:

```
var m = new Mock<ReportBuilder<Report>>();
m.SetupProperty(r => r.SomeThing, 19);
```

but note that all your properties have to be `virtual` or `abstract`.

So if this is not the case (and you can't or don't want to change this), you could either extract an `interface` from your base class and use this (if you're willing to change your code accordingly), or simply create a stub/mock by subclassing:

```
public class StubReportBuilder : ReportBuilder<Report>
{
    public override Int32 SomeThing { get { return 42; } set { } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic: Yes, it was the lack of virtual properties that was catching me out