# How to mock a Generic Abstract Class using MOQ?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm fairly experienced when mocking interfaces and this is the 1st time that im trying to mock Generic Abstract classes. I'm updating code that a previous developer has worked on and has resigned already. I'm trying to mock a generic abstract class using MOQ, the code is as below

```
public abstract class AbstractView<TView, TTranslation, TProperty, TPropertyView> : TranslatableEntity<TTranslation>, IView
        where TView : IView, new()
        where TTranslation :  ITranslation 
        where TProperty : BaseEntity, IProp
        where TPropertyView : AbstractPropertyView<TView,TProperty>, new() 
    {
```

I saw this one here in StackOverflow but when i tried it it doesnt seem to work

[StackOverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143629/how-to-mock-a-generic-abstract-class)

Im getting incorrect number of Type parameters error when I try the one above.

I asked some of the people here and they also dont have a clue. Can anyone teach me how can i mock such an abstract class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the mocking code you've tried look like, and what error are you actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't show your actual mocking code, but you can mock this class just fine.

Here's an example. Given the following interfaces/classes:

public interface IView { }

```
class DummyView : IView { }
public interface ITranslation { }
public interface IProp { }
public class BaseEntity : IProp {}
public class AbstractPropertyView<TView,TProperty> { }
public abstract class TranslatableEntity<TTranslation> { }

public abstract class AbstractView<TView, TTranslation, TProperty, TPropertyView> : TranslatableEntity<TTranslation>, IView
        where TView : IView, new()
        where TTranslation :  ITranslation 
        where TProperty : BaseEntity, IProp
        where TPropertyView : AbstractPropertyView<TView,TProperty>, new() 
{
    public abstract int Foo();
}
```

you can mock it as simple(?) as:

```
var mock = new Mock<AbstractView<DummyView, ITranslation, BaseEntity, AbstractPropertyView<DummyView, BaseEntity>>>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Foo()).Returns(5);
```

Comment: i think im finally getting the point, when mocking abstract classes, you have to pass concrete classes to the Types where a "type with an empty contructor should be supplied and simply supply the interfaces with.. well interfaces, am i correct?

Comment: @user1465073 Yes, the `new()` constraint requires you to provide a type which must have a public parameterless constructor. This has nothing to do with the fact that you mock an abstract class. It would be the same if you have to specify a type parameter anywhere else. You have to fullfill the constraints. If you use an interface or a concrete class for the other type parameters does not matter (it's up to you and your use case, you could use both).

Comment: i see, does that make sense and yes i was getting an error of something like

"must pass an object with an empty constructor" and i was so contrained that i musnt use concrete classes when creating a mock.

thanks La